# Limits to infinity - some wonders

Tags: calculus, limits

$a_n \to 0$ , $b_n \to \infty$

Is it true that:
A) $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n - b_n) = -\infty$$
B)$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$$

Well about A I couldn't find a counter example so I'm tending to say that A is true.
About B I think its true too but I know that $\infty $ limits tend to be tricker than the human logic.
I also curios what will happen if I do:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$$  Will the limit in this case be $\infty$?

Comment: For $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$, consider $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $b_n=n$

Comment: @Henry Is it mean that C can also diverges? cause I said its $-\infty$ or $infty$ but now after seeing your example it looks like it can also diverge if I got it correctly

Comment: @kfir124: yes, it can diverge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are true by arithmetic of limits:

sum of limits acts like you would expect as far it's not "$\infty-\infty$", and for B consider $|a_n/b_n|\le |1/b_n|$ starting at some $N$

$C$ is false, you could get for example limit $-\infty$:
$a_n=-1/n$, $b_n=n$.

while: $b_n/a_n=-n^2\rightarrow -\infty $

Comment: is $\infty - \infty$ undefined?

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is underfined. It could be $0$ ($lim n-n$), $\infty$ ($lim n^2-n$), $-\infty$ ($lim n-n^2$).